# neither offset or position methods are not getting any values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

The point for this script is to make a scrollbar out of a vertically draggable element, but In order to have the scroll-able content to scroll, I need to know the position of the scrollbar.

The function that gets the value of its position gets `NaN` for some reason...

Here is the code for the draggable element:

```
$("#scrollbar-thumb").draggable({ 
        axis: "y",
        containment: "#scrollbar-track",
        drag: 
            function( event, ui ) {
                var position = $(this).offset();
                // I've also tried $(this).position and $(this).position.top
                ...
                //...
                //Some other code for the scrollbar
            }
        });
//End of code
```

NOTE: the scrollbar does have a position set before hand inside my CSS

Comment: Have you tried [`ui.offset`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag)?

Comment: Also have you tried $(this).offset().top ?

Comment: I have tried offset top and it returned an error. I'll try again